# How to get location.href on either secure or non-secure http request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following statement to get the href location of my iframe window...

```
var mbackwindow = document.getElementById("mframe").contentWindow.location.href;
```

depending on how I load the initial page, the console.log(mbackwindow) will show me either  `http://something/page/stuff.html`, or `https://something/page/stuff.html`

From my variable `mbackwindow,` I want to get the "/page/stuff.html", no matter if the location is coming from http or https.  How I collect that via javascript / jquery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `window.location` property:

```
window.location.pathname
```

So in your case, use:

```
var mbackwindow = document.getElementById("mframe").contentWindow.location.pathname;
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties

Answer (score 1):

instead of href use pathname

```
document.getElementById("mframe").contentWindow.location.pathname
```